# How to place figure relatively to other figure in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, context-mkiv

I have two figures. I need to place first figure with `width=10cm` and then place second figure with same width but it's center must be shifted to right by 9cm and down by 5cm relatively to center of first picture.

I also need the text do not cross with pictures, i.e. I need this construction behaves just like one usual picture.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the overlay environment to place the two images on top of each
other. Then adjust the relative position of the second figure with the
`\offset` command.

```
\useMPlibrary
  [dum]

\setupexternalfigures
  [width=10cm]

\starttext
  \startoverlay
    {\externalfigure}
    {\offset[x=9cm, y=5cm]{\externalfigure}}
  \stopoverlay
\stoptext
```

[image: result]

*EDIT:* The reason subsequent text overlays the second image is that the `\offset` command does not adjust the bounding box, which is mostly what is desired. You can visually trace that using the `\showboxes` command.

To fix this I present two solutions. The first one creates a `\vbox` using the higher level command `\frame` with a height of *image height + vertical shiftwidth / 2 = 12.5cm* which creates a box of the correct height, so subsequent text does not overprint the image.

```
\setuppapersize
  [A3]

\useMPlibrary
  [dum]

\setupexternalfigures
  [width=10cm]

\defineframed
  [overlayframe]
  [frame=off,
   offset=overlay,
   height=12.5cm,
   align=top]

\starttext
  \overlayframe{%%
    \startoverlay
      {\externalfigure}
      {\offset[x=9cm, y=5cm]{\externalfigure}}
  \stopoverlay}
  \input knuth
\stoptext
```

[image: result-fix]

The second solution inserts vertical space by using a `\vskip`.

```
\setuppapersize
  [A3]

\useMPlibrary
  [dum]

\setupexternalfigures
  [width=10cm]

\starttext
  \startoverlay
    {\externalfigure}
    {\offset[x=9cm, y=5cm]{\externalfigure}}
  \stopoverlay

  \godown [\dimexpr 5cm+\lineheight\relax]
  \input knuth
\stoptext
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: I t works bad with text http://bpaste.net/show/173690/ and this is result http://haimage.ru/i/127/